# Simplifying logarithmic inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms

I have a dumb question:
given $40log_2(n)≤n^3$, how does that simplify to $40≤n^2$?

This came up in a study question and I don't understand how they got from one to the other. I'm assuming that $log_2(n)/n$ somehow removes the log but I don't know for sure, can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Could you please specify the domain of $n$?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-40log2%28x%29%3E%3D0 This shows that your implication is wrong. Therefore, $40 \leq n^2$ is not a simplification, is just a sufficient condition for $n$ to satisfy the log inequality.

Comment: Just a simple counterexample: take $n=1.$ The log inequality is satisfied, but what about the other? Please check again the statement of the problem.

Comment: The question was asked in the context of learning about Big O notation in CompSci, so the domain is for all n >= 2.
Perhaps simplify is not the correct term; This inequality was in the answer given to me, the former inequality was true if the latter was true, but I don't understand where they got the latter inequality.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If $n\geq 2$, then for $n=5$, it is, again, not true. See the Wolfram Alpha link above.

Comment: But the inequality is only correct when $n≥sqrt(40)$, which is my problem; I need to find what values of $n$ make the inequality true, and in the answer given they simplify the initial inequality from $40log_2(n)≤n^3$ to $n≤sqrt(40)$, and the step I posted is the only step where I don't understand how they went from the former to the latter.

Comment: To be clear, the former inequality holds for $n\geq 4.40701$, and the latter holds for $n \geq sqrt(40) \approx 6.32456.$ (Given the domain $n\geq 2$). If we think this in terms of **natural** numbers, only $n=5$ and $n=6$ are the problems for the implication $40log_2(n)\leq n^3 \Rightarrow n^2\geq 40.$

Comment: My apologies I think I see my error: this inequality is in the context of finding $M$ and $c$ values for a Big O comparison so I think I'm asking the wrong question.

Perhaps the question I should ask is, "what steps are involved in solving $40log_2(n) ≤ n^3$ for $n$?"

Comment: You need Lambert function.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Let, $n=2^k$

$$40k≤2^{3k}$$

$$2^{3k}≥3k\times \frac{40}{3}$$

$$2^m≥ \frac{40}{3}m, m=3\log_2n, n>0$$

To solve this inequality, we need [Lambert W function.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

We have exactly $2$ real solutions:

$$0<n≤e^{-1/3 W(-(3 \log(2))/40)}$$

$$n≥e^{-1/3 W_{-1}(-(3 \log(2))/40)}$$